# What is the plural of gif?

Tags: plural-forms

What is the plural of *'gif'*?

*'Gifs'*, *'Gifes'* or is it simply *'Gif'* itself?. When I type **gifs** or **gifes**, the spellchecker tells me they are both incorrect.

Why does that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIF is an [acronym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acronym) that means Graphics Interchange Format.

The plural of GIF is GIFs.

Sometimes something that  was  originally an  acronym is  used as "a regular word" (see [scuba](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scuba)).

The plural of *gif* is *gifs*.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use gif/gifs formally?

Comment: @Mattew Well, I would not, so my advice to you would be not to.